# Bug in jomsocial version 2.8.2

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5, joomla-extensions

I'm having a problem regarding about the jomsocial which I have noticed just now and that is when we are creating any discussion topics in jomsocial then anyone can able to delete it or edit it without logging in or even he is not the admin of that group. I really don't know why it's been like that. Does anyone know about its fix?

Comment: This is not the right place to alert for a Jomsocial bug. Go to the official website: http://www.jomsocial.com/

Answer (score 0):

I've solved it as there was a problem regarding about my acl where i gave the permission that public and registered members can be able to edit and delete anything.